# Preventing refresh React App on submission of form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, button, input

Each time I click enter when typing in the form, the app refreshes.

I am trying to capture the input of the form as a value and set the state as that value.

```
<form>
         <input
            value={input}
            disabled={!channelId}
            onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="what's on your mind..."
          />
          <button
            type="submit"
            disabled={!channelId}
            className="chat__inputButton"
          >
            Send
          </button>
        </form>
```

Here is the code. I have tried to manipulate the code using preventDefault(), but that isn't keeping the app from refreshing.

For reference, I am following along with this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zc1loX80TX8

I tried using preventDefault(), but that didn't work.

When I remove onChange from the input, I am not able to type in the input form.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the type submit on button and have a event on form as `onSubmit`

In `onSubmit={handleSubmit}` say... It triggers same function for keyboard events too ....

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button element requires an `onClick` prop, then pass it a function that will also call the `preventDefault` function on the *event object* , the code example:

```
...
 const submitForm = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setInput("") // "Resets" input field
  //Your functionality...
 }
...
return (
...
 <button
  onClick={submitForm}
  //Remaining attributes...
 >
  Send
 </button>
...
```